# Find the combination that minimizes a cost function

Tags: matlab, combinations, minimize

I am facing a problem and I would be grateful to anyone that could help. The problem is the following:

Consider that we have a vector `D = [D1;D2;D3;...;DN]` and a set of time instances `TI = {t1,t2,t3,...,tM}`. Each element of vector `D`, `Di`, corresponds to a subset of `TI`. For example `D1` could correspond to time instances `{t1,t2,t3}` and D2 to `{t2,t4,t5}`.

I would like to find the combination of elements of `D` that corresponds to all elements of `TI`, without any of these being taken into account more than once, and at the same time minimizes the cost function `sum(Dj)`. `Dj` are elements of vector `D` and each one corresponds to a set of time instances.

Let me give an example. Let us consider a vector

```
D = [15;10;5;2;35;15;25;25;25;30;45;5;1;40]
```

and a set

```
TI={5,10,15,20,25,30}
```

Each of D elements corresponds to

```
{[5 15];[5 20];[5 25];[5 30];[5 15 20];[5 20 25];[5 15 30];[5 20 25 30];[10 15];[10 20];[10 25];[10 15 20];[10 15 20 25];[10 30]}
```

respectively, e.g. D(1)=15 corresponds to time instance [5 15].

The solution that the procedure has to come up with is that the combination of D(4) and D(12), i.e. 2 and 1 respectively, has the minimum sum and correspond to all time instances.

I have to mention that the procedure has to be able to work with large vectors.

Thanks for every attempt to help!

Comment: My approach is the following: I start using combntns function and I'm trying several combinations of the elements of D. After that i check for which combinations all time instances are considered and none is taken into account twice. Then i take as the solution the combination with the minimum sum. My problem is that my approach is really slow and i'm looking for different approaches that could make the procedure faster.

Comment: use matlab's `bintprog`

Comment: I just got through. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this is what I think: you have a set of time instances. Then you have a set of some of its subsets, and each subset has a weight. And you would then like to reconstruct the whole set with minimal cost?

Comment: @DedekMraz And the weight should be binary.

Comment: @Shai Could you elaborate because the implementation of bintprog is not that clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: @ApostolosMilioudis - see @MinLin's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15207017/1714410) on how to use `bintprog`

Comment: @Shai Consider that you called bintprog and the solution corresponds to the minimum but is not exactly what you want. Can you recall bintprog and say that it should not take into account the solution x that gave earlier?

Comment: @ToLosMil - consider adding a constraint that exclude the previous solution.

Comment: @Shai I thought about it but I couldn't come up with a way to do that. Do you have you any idea?

Comment: @ToLosMil - open another question about it.

Comment: @Shai This is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15947453/2067480) of the new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary weight vector x places a weight on each D_i.

Let f=[D1;D2;...;DN].

Column j of A, A_j is a binary vector.

A_jk is 1 if D_j corresponds to Tk, else is zero.

The problem is:

```
min f^T*x  s.t.  A*x=1;
```

Then use [bintprog](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/bintprog.html) to solve.

```
x = bintprog(f,[],[],A,ones(M,1))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort and help!

Comment: Consider that you called bintprog and the solution corresponds to the minimum but is not exactly what you want. Can you recall bintprog and say that it should not take into account the solution x that gave earlier?

Comment: integer programming cannot garantee global optimal. It is possible that you have a solution that is better than what intprog produce.