# Iterative use of bintprog on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, combinatorics, linear-programming

We have a problem formulation as shown in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15207017/2067480).

Considering that the first call of `bintprog` gives a solution `x` that after some post processing does not adequately addresses the physical problem, is it possible to recall `bintprog` and exclude the prior solution `x`?

Comment: Why not just add it as a constraint?

Comment: @Bitwise You are allowed to add two types of constraints to `bintprog`. The first one corresponds to inequalities and the second one to equalities. I have already specific arguments to the equality constraints and I can not figure out a way to incorporate the inequality constraints for what I want. Have you any idea?

Comment: How about an inequality? if you got x=3 add x<=2 and -x<=-4. Or is this not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a nogood cut.

Suppose you find a solution \hat{x} that you then decide is infeasible (through some sort of post-processing). Let x and \hat{x} be indexed by i.

You can add a constraint of the following form:

```
\sum_{i : \hat{x}_i = 0} x_i + \sum_{i : \hat{x} = 1} (1-x_i) \geq 1
```

This constraint is an example of a no-good cut: the solution must differ from \hat{x} by at least one index i, otherwise it is infeasible. If your variables are not binary no-goods can be a little more complex.

You can add a no-good to your solution by appending the constraint as a row to your constraint matrix and re-solving with the bintprog() function. I'll leave it to you to you rewrite it in the MATLAB notation.

You didn't say what your post-processing does, but it would be even better if the post-processing could infer from your solution \hat{x} that other solutions are also infeasible, and you can add more than one row per iteration. This is a form of logic-based Benders decomposition, and the inference of other infeasible solutions is called solving an inference dual (as opposed to standard Benders decomposition, where you're solving the linear programming dual).  [More on logic based Benders decomposition](http://wpweb2.tepper.cmu.edu/jnh/benders2.pdf) from the man who coined the term, John Hooker of CMU.

Sorry for the formatting. I need to go but I'll figure out a way to display equations more nicely later.